# Tkinter can't increase frame/grid row height

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I can't find a way to increase the height of the frame containing Treeview. I'm using grid because I'm going to add more widgets later on. I've tried doing these but none of them seem to work:

- defining the frame height when creating it
- rowspan
- grid_rowconfigure(weight)
- grid_rowconfigure(minsize)

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

class ViewWindow(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.root.resizable(False,False)
        self.root.geometry('1000x700+500+150')
        self.root.title('View Appointments')
        self.widgets()

    def widgets(self):
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self.root, width=1000, height=81, background='blue')
        self.canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=20)
        self.header = tk.Label(self.root, text="ABC", background='blue', font=("",50), fg='white')
        self.header.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=20, sticky="W")
        self.topLeftLabel = tk.Label(self.root, text="DEF",font=("",50))
        self.topLeftLabel.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="W", columnspan=20)

        self.frame = tk.Frame(self.root, height=1000, borderwidth=1)
        self.frame.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky="NEWS", columnspan=18, rowspan=20)
        
        ###creating table
        self.table = ttk.Treeview(self.frame)
        self.table["columns"]=("a","b","c","d","e")
        self.table.column("#0")
        self.table.column("a", width=100)
        self.table.column("b", width=100)
        self.table.column("c", width=200)
        self.table.column("d", width=150)
        self.table.column("e", width=100)
        
        self.table.heading("#0")
        self.table.heading("a", text="a",anchor=tk.W)
        self.table.heading("b", text="b",anchor=tk.W)
        self.table.heading("c", text="c",anchor=tk.W)
        self.table.heading("d", text="d",anchor=tk.W)
        self.table.heading("e", text="e",anchor=tk.W)
        self.table['show'] = 'headings'
        
        ###random data
        for i in range(20):
            self.table.insert("",i, value=(i,i,i,i,i))
            
        self.table.pack(fill='both')
        self.root.grid_rowconfigure(2, weight=1)
        self.root.grid_rowconfigure(2, minsize=1000)

def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = ViewWindow(root)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pack the Frame containing the TreeView:

```
self.table.pack(expand=tk.YES, fill=tk.BOTH)
```